# Combination of code first and database first approach

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations, edmx

Is it possible that we can use entity framework power tool to import pre created stored procedures but this should be in code first approach.

What I am think is that
1) I will create a code first project.
2) With entity framework power tool i will generate edmx from context.
3) I will import my stored procedures.
4) I will provide sql script which will create stored procedure with SQL() function in migration.
5) The next time when a fresh database is used, the procedure will be created from script and it will be mapped with edmx.

Please provide any details about it.

Comment: You should have a look at the "EF reverse poco" template

Comment: You want code first from an existing database. Don't mess with EDMX - they are going away. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/JJ200620.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Reverse poco is just awesome. Thanks ErikEJ